# Connect to oracle table from Spring boot JPA , without @Entity annotation & @Id

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to map a pojo to oracle table or view without using @Entity and Id. I dont have identifier column in that view. I understand @Entity requires @Id. Is there a different annotation? Should I use JDBC instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [No primary key](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key) section on wikibooks.

> Sometimes your object or table has no primary key. The best solution
>   in this case is normally to add a generated id to the object and
>   table. If you do not have this option, sometimes there is a column or
>   set of columns in the table that make up a unique value. You can use
>   this unique set of columns as your id in JPA. The JPA Id does not
>   always have to match the database table primary key constraint, nor is
>   a primary key or a unique constraint required.
>
> If your table truly has no unique columns, then use all of the columns
>   as the id. Typically when this occurs the data is read-only, so even
>   if the table allows duplicate rows with the same values, the objects
>   will be the same anyway, so it does not matter that JPA thinks they
>   are the same object. The issue with allowing updates and deletes is
>   that there is no way to uniquely identify the object's row, so all of
>   the matching rows will be updated or deleted.
>
> If your object does not have an id, but its table does, this is fine.
>   Make the object an Embeddable object, embeddable objects do not have
>   ids. You will need a Entity that contains this Embeddable to persist
>   and query it.